# Change font of label from a button?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a label in center of my screen and would like for the user to be able to change the font of this label. Can I access the font feature of the label programmatically, so that I can  define and specify a function that would enable the user to do so?

Comment: *Can I access the font feature of the label programmatically...?* Sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIFont *myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:15];
[mylabel setFont:myFont];
```